Turtle academy scalable robot
I used Transum online logo to create a function that draws a robot. I want to scale the robot by changing the parameters when calling the function but then the arms are detached from the body if I make the robot smaller. Someone suggested I use the tile  (~) sign??? but I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions will be super welcome. Thanks
TO DRAW_RECT :width :height :color  
  SETPC :color  
  PD  
  RT 90  
  FD :width  
  RT 90  
  FD :height  
  RT 90  
  FD :width  
  RT 90  
  FD :height  
  RT 90  
  PU  
END  
  
TO ROBOT :size  
  ; Draw body  
  DRAW_RECT :size :size "blue  
  ; Draw head  
  PU  
  BK :size/2  
  LT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  RT 90  
  PD  
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "red  
  ; Draw left arm  
  PU  
  BK :size/2  
  LT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  LT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  RT 90  
  PD  
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "green  
  ; Draw right arm  
  PU  
  BK :size/2  
  RT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  RT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  LT 90  
  PD  
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "green  
  ; Draw left leg  
  PU  
  BK :size/2  
  LT 90  
  FD :size/2  
  LT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  RT 90  
  PD  
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "green  
  ; Draw right leg  
  PU  
  BK :size/2  
  RT 90  
  FD :size/2  
  RT 90  
  FD :size/4  
  LT 90  
  PD  
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "green  
END


@DarkBee thanks for editing the code, it draws the shapes but they need a co-oridnate point for each rectangle to go in the correct place. At the moment it draws the rectangles in a disconnected pattern. I need to be able to scale the coordinate positions according to the size of the robot. Any ideas? Thanks

TO DRAW_RECT :width :height :color
  SETPC :color
  PD
  RT 90
  FD :width
  RT 90
  FD :height
  RT 90
  FD :width
  RT 90
  FD :height
  RT 90
  PU
END


TO ROBOT :size

  ; Draw body
  DRAW_RECT :size :size "blue

  ; Draw left arm
  PU
  BK :size/2
  LT 90
  PD
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "red

  ; Draw right arm
  PU
  FD :size*1.5
  LT 90
  PD

  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "yellow

  ; Draw head
  PU
  BK :size/1.5
  LT 180
  PD
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "purple

  ; Draw left leg
  PU
  BK :size
  RT 90
  FD :size/10
  PD
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "black

  ; Draw right leg
  PU
  RT 90
  BK :size/2
  RT 180
  PD
  DRAW_RECT :size/2 :size/4 "green

END
CS
ROBOT 90
